# Require.js Can't Load Library That Defines its Own Alias

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to bring the Underscore.String library in to a Require.js project.  The library is setup to support AMD, with the following code:

```
} else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // Register as a named module with AMD.
    define('underscore.string', [], function() {
        return _s;
    });
```

But I have a problem: I don't keep the library in my root path, I keep it in "ext/underscore.string".  This seems to make it impossible to require the library.

I have tried requiring both `"ext/underscore.string"` and `"underscore.string"`, with and without defining a path (of `"underscore.string": "ext/underscore.string"`).  When I don't have a path, and I require "underscore.string" the file (unsurprisingly) doesn't load, and in all other cases the file loads but the library doesn't get defined.

If I try to reference the library afterwards I get:

> Error: Module name "underscore.string" has not been loaded yet for
>   context:

... even if I do so immediately after the define line (in the code above)!  In other words, if I change the code to

```
define('underscore.string', [], function() {
    return _s;
});
console.log(require('underscore.string'))
```

Require tells me that "underscore.string" hasn't been loaded yet!

Can anyone help me figure out how I can bring this library in to my codebase?

Comment: Is the file named `{path}/ext/underscore.string.js`, or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly; my `baseUrl` is `assets/js` and the library is in `assets/js/ext/underscore.string.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your require configuration do:

```
var require = {
    ...
    map: {
        "*": {
            "underscore.string": "path/to/file/disregarding/baseUrl"
        }
    }
};
```

NOTE: The path to file should *include* the `baseUrl`, so in your case and assuming `baseUrl="scripts"`, it would be something like:

```
"scripts/ext/underscore.string.js"
```

NOTE 2: It needs the `.js` extension, i.e. it is exact file name.

Comment: Ah, that sounds perfect ... except it doesn't work :-(  When I try that appropach the map seems to work: underscore.string does get loaded (I can tell if I put a debugger in), but the function that gets passed to the define never gets called (again, I can tell from a debugger line).  The module that requires `underscore.string` then (after loading the file) gets `undefined` as the value for the module, which makes sense since the function that does `return _s` never gets run.  Any thoughts on how to get it to run?

Comment: At least we got one step ahead. Can you try changing the *key* to the map from `"underscore.string"` to e.g. `"underscore-string"` (and modify the require call accordingly). RequireJS may think `.string` is a file extension - just to exclude this case.

Comment: That worked ... almost.  I not only had to change the map (as you suggested), but then I also had to add `'underscore.string': 'ext/underscore.string'` to `paths`.  When I did that however I was finally able to import the library!  Thanks.